# apex class not populating value

Tags: apex

How to check integer is not null in apex class, in my apex class I used integer == null then I am populating `cObj.DCS_Auto_Number__c = 1` but my class is not populating value at all.

Can anyone help me out in this issue, my apex class is below.

```
for(Build_Cycle__c bObj : buildCycleList){
    Integer length = integer.valueOf(bObj.Action_Items__r[0].DCS_Auto_Number__c);
    for(Action_Item__c cObj : actionItemList){
        if(bObj.Id == cObj.DCS_Build_Cycle__c){
            if(length == null){
                cObj.DCS_Auto_Number__c = 1; 
            }else{
                length++;
                cObj.DCS_Auto_Number__c = length;    
            }
        }
    }        
}
```

Comment: What type of field is `DCS_Auto_Number__c` ?

Comment: @OleksandrBerehovskyi, it is a number field

Comment: @Venkat Debug this value `length` and see what it shows. Ideally, it should be `null` unless you have any default value set for it or you have assigned any value to it.

Comment: what is `actionItemList` do you mean it is `bObj.Action_Items__r`?